# Android things 0.5.1 issues with videoview/mediaplayer/can't connect to wifi

Tags: android, camera, raspberry-pi, android-things

I build android things 0.5.1 dev-preview on Raspberry Pi. The main idea was to write a program that will work on raspberry with Android OS, and it was supposed to open the raspicam, let us record video, take photo etc.. But it doesn't work as expected. The local, small issues are
1. In the 0.4.1 version, I was able to connect to wifi as described here (https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html), while in 0.5.1 I am not able. Is this issue comes from the version of Android things that I have built?
2. In the 0.4.1 I have used media player/video view to play video from the web, but now I have only the sound and black screen.  Does anyone encountered this issues, and how did you solve them. Or is there any solution at all?

Comment: if you want help, you need to show people exactly how to reproduce your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The first step will be to plug in an ethernet cable and connect that way.  Then you will connect to a monitor to determine your RPi's ip address.  Next run:

$ ./adb connect ip_address
$ ./adb shell

Then you will run the following command in the adb shell.  The key here is put "quotes" around your passphrase and your network name.

    `am startservice \

    -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \

    -a WifiSetupService.Connect \

    -e ssid "network_name" \

    -e passphrase "password"`

Now turn off your RPi3 and unplug the ethernet cable.  Turn the RPi3 back on and wait a minute and the Wifi ip address should pop up.